# What is the API for unregistering service workers in Chrome >= 44?

Tags: service-worker

I'm trying to unregister a service worker that's already installed. I understand that the registration promise passes the registration as an argument to the success function and I could store that in some scope, but that wouldn't work after a page reload (I'd like to be able to unregister a worker that's been installed in a previous session). I've tried to look for some ID defined on the registration that would allow me to retrieve it later on, but that doesn't seem to exist.

[This page](https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/issues/233) mentions navigator.serviceWorker.unregister (that would take the scope as an argument) but that's not defined in my environment (Chrome 44, Linux). Is it just not implemented yet? Is there a workaround I could use for the time being?

Comment: Show us the code you have done so far. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From a document that's controlled by a SW, this will unregister it (CR41+):

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(function(r) { 
  r.unregister();
});
```

In Chrome, you can also inspect which SWs are active and unregister them from chrome://serviceworker-internals

Comment: is there a way in case of waiting status, to force update service worker and, so cause new tab with application to use new service worker in active state ? In other words - how to update service worker and not cause download all resources by page with service worker status installing.